# How not to specify the port to the site when forwarding ports?

Tags: nginx, nat

I have a NAT setup with port forwarding of external ip port 7777 to internal ip port 443.

But the site can only be accessed at this address `my-site.com:7777`.

How to make it so that when you go to the site do not need to specify port 7777?

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        #ssl on;

        ssl_certificate         /home/username/apps/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/username/apps/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /home/username/apps/chain.pem;

        server_name www.my-site.com my-site.com;

        root /home/username/apps/dist;

        index index.html;

        location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-site.com my-site.com;
    return 301 https://my-site.com$request_uri;
    access_log off;
}
```

Comment: Forward port 443 instead of 7777.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider port 443 of the external ip address is busy

Comment: Then you don't. HTTP default port is 80, HTTPS default port is 443, if they are already in use then you will always need to specify a different port. (assuming 443 is being used by your routers admin interface you may be able to stop it listening externally)

Comment: Then you don't do port forwarding, but configure the existing web server to "reverse proxy" a specific URL prefix and/or path to the internal application running on port 7777 i.e. the web server hosts www.example.com from local content and either reverse proxies the `www.example.com/my-app/` to `internal-host:7777/my-app` or set up a specic (sub-) domain  `my-app.example.com` and reverse proxy that to   `internal-host:7777[/my-app]`

Comment: You have run into a limitation of NAPT. This is one of the reasons for IPv6 that restores the IP end-to-end paradigm broken by NAPT on IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look at your application to change the port, because exposing a non-secure port to the public is not recommended. And insecure. But if your application is port forwarded to port 443 you might be able to pick it up internally.